# Why Would Windows 10 Task Manager's Details Show Some Processes' Operating System Context As An Older Version?

Tags: windows-10, operating-systems, task-manager

I have a Windows 10 Machine, but as I was looking at the Task Manager's Details tab, I saw the corresponding "Operating System Context" entry of some processes show an older OS version. The image below illustrates what I am trying to communicate:

[image: Windows 10 Task Manager Details Tab. The Operating System Context column shows an older OS version for some processes]

Why would these processes show an older OS version as their context?

Comment: You may wish to turn OFF the column "Operating System Context"   .  My Printer (HP 8610) says Vista and it woks well in Windows 11. So this is perhaps a column that you do not need and simply adds confusing details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the specific application/s not having had their application manifest changed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/win7appqual/compatibility---application-manifest?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Nothing to worry about here.
I assume you didn't create these programs? If so, you can set the application manifest up using the below link for reference. If these aren't your programs it simply means whoever made them (for the Vista case anyway) hasn't inputted anything at all.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15808967/application-running-in-windows-vista-context-by-default